# Animations with CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a "simple" animation with css & html. I have an image, which I want to be hidden for the **first 18 seconds** when entering the page, after that, the image will be **visible** and the **animation will begin**.
The animation should go to the sides of the screen in square shape for **about 30 seconds**, and then it will disappear. (Like from bottom left to bottom right, to top right, right bottom in a loop).

I managed to do half of it, kinda. The image hidden thing isn't working, the animation is working but it is not stopping after 30 seconds and also, when I opened my website on another computer size, the img didn't touch the side like it did with my laptop (different screen size). If you could provide me with an answer I will appreciate it, THANKS!

What I tried:

HTML:

```css
.col-5 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 3s 100;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: myfirst 3s 100;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}


/* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
  0% {
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 440px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  25% {
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
  }
  50% {
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 1020px;
  }
  75% {
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 440px;
    left: 1020px;
  }
  100% {
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 440px;
    left: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='col-5'>
  <img style="margin-left: 0%; margin-top: 31%;" src="..\static\kingjulien_iliketo1.gif" style="position:relative;" width="480" height="270" class="juliengif1"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things to mention: you have more than one inline style on the image; if you are going to use inline style, list all attributes in one *`style =""`* list. Preferably, use a class: you have a class juliengif1 named in the image, but not defined in the css. I have added the attributes to my snippet/ removed them from the inline style.
(which could be as `style="margin-left: 0%; margin-top: 31%; position:relative; width:480px; height:270px;"` - css is tidier!)

As for size, well you should investigate media-queries, and compose media queries to apply to your animation in order to accommodate different screen sizes.

I recommend an `alt` tag onto your image just in case the image doesn't show. 
I  changed the duration of the animation to 30s ("`myfirst 30s`"), so that the animation would stop as you wish, after 30 seconds.  I have added `background-color`s to the transitional moves (which begin after an 18s delay). When you run it you will see that each side of the transition lasts approx 7.5 seconds (30s/4)

Hope this helps

Rachel

```css
#juliengif1 {
  margin-left: 0%;
  top: 31%;
  position: relative;
  width: 480px;
  height: 270px;
  background-color:blue;
}

.col-5 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation: myfirst 30s;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  -webkit-animation-direction: normal;
  /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */
  animation: myfirst 30s ;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

/*Safari 4.0 - 8.0*/

@-webkit-keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {background: red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    25%  {background: yellow; left: 400px; top: 0px;}
    50%  {background: red; left: 400px; top: 300px;}
    75%  {background: yellow; left: 0px; top: 300px;}
    100% {background: red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}

@keyframes myfirst {
    0%   {background: red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
    25%  {background: yellow; left: 400px; top: 0px;}
    50%  {background: red; left: 400px; top: 300px;}
    75%  {background: yellow; left: 0px; top: 300px;}
    100% {background: red; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
}
```

```html
<div class='col-5'>
  <img id="juliengif1" src="..\static\kingjulien_iliketo1.gif" alt="hi">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`animation:bottomleft 1s linear 1s forwards, .....` second 1s is first start delay. you can do it 18s. i hope this is answer you want to.

```css
body {
  margin:0;
}

.box {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  background:#262626;
  animation:bottomleft 1s linear 1s forwards, rightbottom 1s linear 2s forwards, righttop 1s linear 3s forwards, lefttop 1s linear 4s forwards;
  position:absolute;
  visibility:hidden
} 

@keyframes bottomleft {
  to {margin-top:calc(100vh - 50px);visibility:visible}
}

@keyframes rightbottom {
  to {margin-left:calc(100vw - 50px)}
}

@keyframes righttop {
  to {transform:translateY(calc(-100vh + 50px))}
}

@keyframes lefttop {
  to{margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:calc(100vh - 50px);transform:translateX(calc(-100vw + 50px));}
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```